# @FontFace not working in Safari

Tags: css, types, fonts, safari

I can not seem to shake this problem!

Safari won't load my custom font. Both Firefox and Chrome work fine.

Any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Clarendon";
src: url('Assets/Fonts/ClarendonLTStd-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
src: url('Assets/Fonts/ClarendonLTStd-Light.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Assets/Fonts/ClarendonLTStd-Light.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('Assets/Fonts/ClarendonLTStd-Light#svgClarendon') format('svg');
     font-weight: light;
     font-style: light;
}
```

Comment: `Assets/Fonts/ClarendonLTStd-Light#svgClarendon` is missing `.svg` before the `#svgClarendon`

Comment: @setek  That shouldn't matter for Safari,  it uses ttf.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr I know, that's why it's not an answer, just a comment.

Comment: Can you do a little debugging?  Try setting `font-weight` and `font-style` to normal and see if it works.  Sometimes Safari plays bad games on few typefaces and other times it does with `font-style`.

Comment: nope nothing, no change unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a page we can view this on, so we can see what's not working for ourselves?